# circular navigation from a ux perpective good or bad? (example provided)

Tags: navigation

I'm playing with the idea of [circular navigation](http://www.deviantart.com/art/circular-navigation-idea-403051331) but I'm not sure if it is a good implementation.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Context is everything. If it makes sense for your purpose, it might be appropriate. Just note that it's atypical, so you may have to get over the familiarity hurdle.

Answer (score 5):

Pie menus (which is the name of the control) can be a good navigation pattern in certain instances. They are for example utilized in Android camera app, where the user presses on the camera view port and a pie menu appears, swiping to one of the items expands that item into sub menu items.

[image]
[image]

It's a good navigation approach in instances such as this, when you want to hide the controls but still make them accessible efficiently utilizing the area of the display.

However, there are some drawbacks:

- **There is no visual hierarchy:**
  Since all the items are the same distance away from the mouse, It’s
  not possible to put the most commonly used items in the position of
  greatest importance. Instead, even less commonly used items are
  placed in a position of great importance. Additionally, it’s usually
  easier to scan a list or even a grid than in a circle.
- **It’s difficult to align text:** Making the interface easily look a bit messy. Plus menu items often variate in label length making it hard to align the pie segment's size. It's better if you can use icons (as in the example above) since then you don't get the problem of differing label lengths. If you can find suitable icons/glyphs to represent the items in your design it could work better (keeping in mind that icons can be hard to interpret if not set by convention).

You can read more [HERE](http://elementaryos.org/journal/argument-against-pie-menus) and [HERE](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/pie-menu/).